# Почему не работает цель на кнопке

Tags: php, битрикс

Не работает цель на JavaScript событии Яндекс Метрики 
Вот код кнопки и вставленная туда цель :

```
<div class="catalog-element-buy_buttons"><?
?><noindex><form class="js-buyform js-buyform<?=$BUY_ID?>" name="buy_form" yaCounter28360211.reachGoal('push_button');return true;>
```

Comment: потому что может быть надо засунуть этот код в какой-то js ивент, к примеру onsubmit()

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<form class="js-buyform js-buyform<?=$BUY_ID?>" name="buy_form" onsubmit="yaCounter28360211.reachGoal('push_button');return true;">
```